# What is T (& var)[N]?

Tags: c++, boost

In `boost/utility/swap.hpp` I have found this piece of code:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
void swap_impl(T (& left)[N], T (& right)[N])
{
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    ::boost_swap_impl::swap_impl(left[i], right[i]);
  }
}
```

What are `left` and `right`? Are they references to arrays? Is this code allowed by C++ ISO standard 2003 or later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reference to an array of type T and length N.

This is a natural extension of C's pointer-to-array syntax, and is supported by C++03.

You could use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%28%26var%29%5B3%5D) to try to parse these complex type declarations.

Comment: Why "static"? The arrays could have automatic storage duration. The main point is that this is a reference to an array, not a pointer to one.

Comment: @Steve: I mean, as contrast to dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

> What are left and right? Are they references to arrays? Is this code allowed by C++ ISO standard 2003 or later?

Yes. They're *references* to arrays.

That means, you can call `swap_impl` as:

```
int a[10]; //array
int b[10];
//...
swap_impl(a,b); //correct
```

But you **cannot** call `swap_impl` as:

```
int *a = new int[10]; //pointer 
int *b = new int[10];
//...
swap_impl(a,b); //compilation error
```

---

Also note that you cannot do even this:

```
int a[10];
int b[11];
//...
swap_impl(a,b); //compilation error - a and b are arrays of different size!
```

Important point:

**- Not only arguments must be arrays, but the arrays must be of same size!**

Comment: Why "automatic"? The arrays could have static storage duration (for instance globals). The main point is that this is a reference to an array, not a pointer to one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to declare a reference to an array of T (of size N) named left and right.  The code is legal C++.

This allows you to pass in:

```
int ones[5] = { 1,1,1,1,1 };
int twos[5] = { 2,2,2,2,2 };

swap_impl(ones, twos);
```

Then template type inference will know that you have T = int and N = 5 and do the in-place swap.  If you mismatch the types or the size, you get a handy compilation failure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is standard C++ allowed from very early on (its basically C with the addition of a reference).

Using typedefs makes it easier to read:

```
int main()
{
    typedef  int (&MyArray)[4];
    int      data[4];
    MyArray  dataRef = data;
}
```

It sort of mirrors the function typedef

```
typedef int (*MyFunc)();
```